# How to cast multiple columns and values of a data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

my data is structured as follows:

```
DT <- data.table(Id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 100, 100, 101, 101, 101), 
                 Date = as.Date(c("1997-01-01", "1997-01-02", "1997-01-03", "1997-01-04", 
                                  "1997-01-02", "1997-01-02", "1997-01-04", "1997-01-03", 
                                  "1997-01-04", "1997-01-04")),
                 group = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
                 Price.1 = c(29, 25, 14, 26, 30, 16, 13, 62, 12,  6), 
                 Price.2 = c(4, 5, 6, 6, 8, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8))

>DT
     Id       Date group Price.1 Price.2
 1:   1 1997-01-01     1      29       4
 2:   1 1997-01-02     1      25       5
 3:   1 1997-01-03     1      14       6
 4:   1 1997-01-04     1      26       6
 5:  10 1997-01-02     1      30       8
 6: 100 1997-01-02     2      16       2
 7: 100 1997-01-04     2      13       3
 8: 101 1997-01-03     2      62       5
 9: 101 1997-01-04     2      12       7
10: 101 1997-01-04     2       6       8
```

I am trying to cast it (using dcast.data.table):

```
dcast.data.table(DT, Id ~ Date, fun = sum, value.var = "Price.1") 
dcast.data.table(DT, Id ~ group, fun = sum, value.var = "Price.1")
dcast.data.table(DT, Id ~ Date, fun = sum, value.var = "Price.2")
dcast.data.table(DT, Id ~ group, fun = sum, value.var = "Price.2")
```

but rather than 4 separate outputs I am trying to get the following:

```
    Id 1997-01-01 1997-01-02 1997-01-03 1997-01-04  1  2   Price
1:   1         29         25         14         26 94  0 Price.1
2:  10          0         30          0          0 30  0 Price.1
3: 100          0         16          0         13  0 29 Price.1
4: 101          0          0         62         18  0 80 Price.1
5:   1          4          5          6          6 21  0 Price.2
6:  10          0          8          0          0  8  0 Price.2
7: 100          0          2          0          3  0  5 Price.2
8: 101          0          0          5         15  0 20 Price.2
```

and my work-around uses rbind, cbind, and merge.

```
cbind(rbind(merge(dcast.data.table(DT, Id ~ Date, fun = sum, value.var = "Price.1"), 
            dcast.data.table(DT, Id ~ group, fun = sum, value.var = "Price.1"), by = "Id", all.x  = T),
      merge(dcast.data.table(DT, Id ~ Date, fun = sum, value.var = "Price.2"),
            dcast.data.table(DT, Id ~ group, fun = sum, value.var = "Price.2"), by = "Id", all.x  = T)),
      Price = c("Price.1","Price.1","Price.1","Price.1","Price.2","Price.2","Price.2","Price.2"))
```

Is there an existing and cleaner way to do this?

Comment: If each `Id` only belongs to one `group`, you could spin off that mapping and thereby simplify your life.

Comment: That is one crazy reshaping problem!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I make the assumption that each `Id` maps to a unique `group` and get rid of that variable, but otherwise this is essentially the same as @user227710's answer.

```
Idg <- unique(DT[,.(Id,group)])
DT[,group:=NULL]

res <- dcast(
  melt(DT, id.vars = c("Id","Date")),
  variable+Id ~ Date,
  value.var = "value",
  fill = 0,
  margins = "Date",
  fun.aggregate = sum
)

# and if you want the group back...
setDT(res) # needed before data.table 1.9.5, where using dcast.data.table is another option
setkey(res,Id)
res[Idg][order(variable,Id)]
```

which gives

```
   variable  Id 1997-01-01 1997-01-02 1997-01-03 1997-01-04 (all) group
1:  Price.1   1         29         25         14         26    94     1
2:  Price.2   1          4          5          6          6    21     1
3:  Price.1  10          0         30          0          0    30     1
4:  Price.2  10          0          8          0          0     8     1
5:  Price.1 100          0         16          0         13    29     2
6:  Price.2 100          0          2          0          3     5     2
7:  Price.1 101          0          0         62         18    80     2
8:  Price.2 101          0          0          5         15    20     2
```

Answer (score 4):

This was really a trial and error: I hope it works.

```
library(data.table) #version 1.9.4
library(reshape2)
kk <- melt(DT,id.vars=c("Id","Date","group"),
                    measure.vars = c("Price.1","Price.2"),
                    value.name = "Price")


dcast(kk, Id + variable + group ~ Date, value.var = "Price", fun = sum,margins="Date")
# ^ use of margins borrowed from @Frank. 


#    Id variable group 1997-01-01 1997-01-02 1997-01-03 1997-01-04 (all)
# 1   1  Price.1     1         29         25         14         26    94
# 2   1  Price.2     1          4          5          6          6    21
# 3  10  Price.1     1          0         30          0          0    30
# 4  10  Price.2     1          0          8          0          0     8
# 5 100  Price.1     2          0         16          0         13    29
# 6 100  Price.2     2          0          2          0          3     5
# 7 101  Price.1     2          0          0         62         18    80
# 8 101  Price.2     2          0          0          5         15    20
```

Answer (score 0):

And just to compare, a solution in `dplyr` (as I have yet to learn how to get my brain to melt things properly.)

```
    # aggregate the data completely 
## (rows 9 & 10 need to be collapsed, and spread works on a single key)
DTT <- 
    DT %>% 
    group_by(Id, Date, group) %>% 
    summarise(Price.1 = sum(Price.1), Price.2 = sum(Price.2)) %>% 
    left_join(DT) %>% 
    unite(id_grp, Id, group, sep = "_") %>% 
    group_by(id_grp) %>% 
    mutate(s1 = sum(Price.1), s2 = sum(Price.2))
# pivot out the index into cartesian (long to wide) for 1st Price set 
DW1 <- 
    DTT %>% 
    select(-Price.2) %>% 
    spread(Date, Price.1) %>% 
    mutate(Price = "Price.1")
# pivot out the index into cartesian (long to wide) for 2nd Price set 
DW2 <- 
    DTT %>% 
    select(-Price.1) %>% 
    spread(Date, Price.2) %>% 
    mutate(Price = "Price.2")
# Bind records back together and make purdy
DWFin <- 
    bind_rows(DW1,DW2) %>% 
    separate(id_grp, c("Id", "group")) %>% 
    mutate(g = group, p = str_sub(Price, -1),
           n1 = ifelse(group == 1 & p == 1, s1, ifelse(group == 1 & p == 2, s2, 0)),
           n2 = ifelse(group == 2 & p == 2, s2, ifelse(group == 2 & p == 1, s1, 0))) %>% 
    select(Id, starts_with("19"), "1" = n1, "2" = n2, Price)
DWFin

Source: local data table [8 x 8]

# tbl_dt [8 × 8]
     Id `1997-01-01` `1997-01-02` `1997-01-03` `1997-01-04`   `1`   `2`   Price
  <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <chr>
1     1           29           25           14           26    94     0 Price.1
2    10           NA           30           NA           NA    30     0 Price.1
3   100           NA           16           NA           13     0    29 Price.1
4   101           NA           NA           62           18     0    80 Price.1
5     1            4            5            6            6    21     0 Price.2
6    10           NA            8           NA           NA     8     0 Price.2
7   100           NA            2           NA            3     0     5 Price.2
8   101           NA           NA            5           15     0    20 Price.2
```