# how to cast to multicolumn in R like Pandas-Style?

Tags: r, pandas, dplyr, reshape

i searched a lot but didn't find anything relevant.

### What I Want:

I'm trying to do a simple groupby and summarising in R.

My preffered output would be with multiindexed columns and multiindexed rows. Multiindexed rows are easy with dplyr, the difficulty are the cols.

### what I already tried:

```
library(dplyr)
cp <- read.table(text="SEX REGION CAR_TYPE JOB EXPOSURE NUMBER
  1   1      1        1   1       70      1
  2   1      1        1   2      154      8
  3   1      1        2   1      210     10
  4   1      1        2   2      21       1
  5   1      2        1   1       77      8
  6   1      2        1   2       90      6
  7   1      2        2   1      105      5
  8   1      2        2   2      140     11
  ")
attach(cp)

cp_gb <- cp %>%
  group_by(SEX, REGION, CAR_TYPE, JOB) %>% 
  summarise(counts=round(sum(NUMBER/EXPOSURE*1000)))

dcast(cp_gb, formula = SEX + REGION ~  CAR_TYPE + JOB, value.var="counts")
```

Now there is the problem that the column index is "melted" into one instead of a multiindexed column, like I know it from Python/Pandas.

**Wrong output:**

```
 SEX REGION 1_1 1_2 2_1 2_2
1      1  14  52  48  48
1      2 104  67  48  79
```

### Example how it would work in Pandas:

```
# clipboard, copy this withoud the comments: 
# SEX REGION CAR_TYPE JOB EXPOSURE NUMBER
# 1   1      1        1   1       70      1
# 2   1      1        1   2      154      8
# 3   1      1        2   1      210     10
# 4   1      1        2   2      21       1
# 5   1      2        1   1       77      8
# 6   1      2        1   2       90      6
# 7   1      2        2   1      105      5
# 8   1      2        2   2      140     11

df = pd.read_clipboard(delim_whitespace=True)

gb = df.groupby(["SEX","REGION", "CAR_TYPE", "JOB"]).sum()
gb['promille_value'] = (gb['NUMBER'] / gb['EXPOSURE'] * 1000).astype(int)
gb = gb[['promille_value']].unstack(level=[2,3])
```

**correct Output**:

```
CAR_TYPE        1   1   2   2
JOB             1   2   1   2
SEX REGION              
1   1           14  51  47  47
1   2           103 66  47  78
```

### (Update) What works (nearly):

I tried to to with ftable, but it only prints ones in the matrix instead of the values of "counts".

```
ftable(cp_gb, col.vars=c("CAR_TYPE","JOB"), row.vars = c("SEX","REGION"))
```

Comment: can you share expected output?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297284/how-to-cast-multiple-columns-and-values-of-a-data-table) may it helps

Comment: you can work along the lines of `aggregate((cp$NUMBER/cp$EXPOSURE*1000), by=list(cp$SEX,cp$REGION,cp$CAR_TYPE, cp$JOB), FUN=sum)
`.

Comment: @mtoto added some example, don't know yet how to format output properly, when i have time to read about that, i'll add it.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli : I tried that. Does the same as the summarise, but i'll lose the column names and there is no "reshaping", which i did with the casting. could you explain further, why this should help?

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Don't see the help from that thread.. could you explain how i get a multiindex on those casted frame?

Comment: You still haven't provided your desired output so I'm just guessing. You could atleast show what the Pandas operation returns.

Comment: Yeah, was a little bit tricky to format in a nice way, sorry! Added now.

Comment: Now that we see the exp. output: I don't believe this is possible in R with `data.frame`s or `tibble`s, as these are essentially just lists of columns and don't have any multicolumn functionality. Would love to see some other solution tough.

Comment: I was able to create the desired format with tabular from tables package.... problem is: this only put ones as values, instead of the values shown above.... I'll add that example later this evening

Comment: While familiar in both environments, I believe R does not render multi-column index (i.e., multiple levels) like Python pandas. Colnames and rownames in R are one-length atomic vectors. You can possibly play with column attributes for further identification. And curious why you need this format as it seems to be for reporting/presentation and R can output such structure in text/markup? Otherwise stick with Python. Both are great tools together!

Comment: Yeah, it's needed exactly for university.. Otherwise i wouldn't have tried it that way and would be very patient with default cast functionality. There are no helps from the tutor. I tried with ftable (see update), but didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ftable accepts lists of factors (data frame) or a table object. Instead of passing the grouped data frame as it is, converting it to a table object first before passing to ftable should get your the counts:

```
# because xtabs expects factors
cp_gb <- cp_gb %>% ungroup %>% mutate_at(1:4, as.factor)
xtabs(counts ~ ., cp_gb) %>%
  ftable(col.vars=c("CAR_TYPE","JOB"), row.vars = c("SEX","REGION")) 


#            CAR_TYPE   1       2
#            JOB        1   2   1   2
# SEX REGION
# 1   1                14  52  48  48
#     2               104  67  48  79
```

There is a difference of 1 in some of counts between R and pandas outputs because you use round in R and truncation (.astype(int)) in python.

Comment: thanks, I'll try that later this day!

Yeah, the truncation was just because i wrote that just down to show the approx. result.